# Не запускаются карты Яндекса

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Сборка собралась нормально, все по инструкции Яндекса. Ошибок никаких не выявлено.

Приложение запускается, но карты не прогружаются.

Вкладка Run:

```
W/yandex.maps: decltype: Unexpected server response: Forbidden. Body :Invalid client information.
    Could not fetch [https://proxy.mob.maps.yandex.net:443/mapkit2/init/2.x/random]
W/yandex.maps: decltype: Unexpected server response: Forbidden. Body :Invalid client information.
    Could not fetch [https://proxy.mob.maps.yandex.net:443/mapkit2/init/2.x/random]
W/yandex.maps: decltype: Unexpected server response: Forbidden. Body :Invalid client information.
    Could not fetch [https://spdy3-proxy.maps.yandex.net:443/mapkit2/init/2.x/random]
W/yandex.maps: decltype: Unexpected server response: Forbidden. Body :Invalid client information.
    Could not fetch [https://spdy3-proxy.maps.yandex.net:443/mapkit2/init/2.x/random]
```

Логи:

```
2020-12-13 10:36:17.090 25913-25913/? W/cmd: Can't find service car_service
2020-12-13 10:36:18.086 195-195/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=25919 uid=2000 name=car_service scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2020-12-13 10:36:18.087 25919-25919/? W/cmd: Can't find service car_service
2020-12-13 10:36:19.100 195-195/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=25925 uid=2000 name=car_service scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

Comment: С этим вам в поддержку maps-api@support.yandex.ru